# export variable in function scope only

Tags: bash

Say I have `a.sh` with `export a="a"` and `b.sh` with export `b="b"`. now in `main.sh`, both `a.sh` and `b.sh` is sourced within a function `funca` and `funcb`:

```
function funca() {
    source a.sh
}

function funcb() {
    source b.sh
}

funca
echo $a $b
funcb
echo $a $b
```

I would like the source command only take effect within the function scope, so after the function return, the export should show empty.

Current output is:

```
a
a b
```

expected output is empty!

Comment: If you are **sure**, that you want your variables to be exported during function execution, you have to manually remove them from the environment at the end of the function. However, this smells like a [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem). Why do you need them  being exported?

Comment: good question,  my usecase is build android source code, the variables is defined by aosp code, but I need do the same in two stage, the first build stage will impact on the next due to export previously. my sample just simplify it for easy understand.

Comment: Exporting a variable puts a name in the environment, which is independent of any global or local scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a variable to be local, you must declare it as local, otherwise it will be global. Even in a function. Even if a file is sourced.

So, that would make `a.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
local a='a'
```

Note that, if you do not `source` the file, but execute it in a separate shell, the variables `a` and `b` wil be global to that second shell, but not 'move up' to the parent shell. ANd they can be exported as well.

```
function funca() {
    bash a.sh
}

function funcb() {
    bash b.sh
}

funca
echo $a $b
funcb
echo $a $b
```

will give you empty as well.

Comment: But with this approach, the variable is not in the environment during function exectuion. The OP explicitly requested, that he wants the variables to be **exported**. We don't know, why this is requested; perhaps `a.sh` or `b.sh` invoke child processes which need the variables in the environment.

Comment: The OP uses the term `export` but expects the behaviour of a local variable. Anyway: with invoking a separate shell (second part of the answer), the export is possible.

Comment: You can use a separate shell, but usually when **sourcing** a file, you want the current process being affected (for instance, some variables being set, or functions defined). If the OP does not want any effect on his process, he would not have use `source` in the first place. I must admit that the question is not asked very clearly, but the problem seems to be having some changes to the environment being undone, which occured during the sourcing process, but keep everything else intact.

Comment: Question of interpretation of the question. Let the OP decide whether the answer is what was looked for.

Answer (score 3):

You should use `declare -x` instead of `export`. They both give variables the *export* attribute, but `declare -x`, if used in a function, does not affect the global scope.

Comment: In what way is `declare -x` different from `export`? According to the man-page, both commands put the variable into the environment.

Comment: @user1934428 inside a function declare -x works differently. try `f() { export a=1; declare -x b=2;}; f; declare -p a b` and you'll see

Comment: AMAZING!!!! I could not deduce this behaviour from the bash man-page (I was reading the part explaining the `declare` command). Could you explain about this feature in your comment? This really seems to solves the OP's problem in the best way.

Comment: @user1934428 done. the manual says declare and typeset make variables *local*, you could have inferred it from that